# Postgres sequence does not reset when deleted and recreated

Tags: postgresql, sequences

I have a Postgres sequence defined with the following code -

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mydb.mytable
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 25
  CACHE 1;
```

I am running this as part of a SQL script on a Postgres 9.5 database.

When I ran the script the first time, the sequence generates integers starting with 1 correctly.

While testing, I dropped the sequence and the table associated with it and re ran the SQL script which re created the sequence. When re created, the sequence is incorrectly generating integers from the last number previously used. Why does it not reset to the minimum value 1 on re create?

Comment: Sounds as if the sequence wasn't actually dropped.

Comment: Do you have a schema named `mydb` ?

Comment: You have `START` value set to 25 in your code. So new sequence will start from 25

Comment: That was the issue - START 25 - I missed it. Thanks all.